# How can I able to use PEM file in aws again?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image]Currently, I am facing an issue related to AWS. A project is already uploaded on AWS server and always connect to that Project by using PEM key of that particular project. But from last week I am not able to connect with the AWS server by using the PEM key. I got one solution for this, as by creating new instance i will be able to got my access on the project but this will make me lose of my whole data & database as a result. Is this occurred due to virus or any thing else? Got stuck over here badly. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Facing the same problem. @Nikhil

Comment: whats the error you are getting when using the same key

Comment: can you ssh with -v option and post the results `ssh -Tv ec2-user@example.com -i ~/mykey.pem`

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP and Wordpress?

Comment: @ArunK Please check for the same

Answer (score 0):

I think the `authorized_keys` file has some incorrect entries. Let's remove the key from the file and add it again.

**remove the host key**

```
ssh-keygen -R [hostname]
```

**ssh again**

```
ssh -Tv ec2-user@example.com -i ~/mykey.pem
```

Comment: can you check and get back to me

Answer (score 0):

In order to use existing EBS volume with data in a new ec2, with a new ssh key:

1. Create a snapshot of the current instance's EBS, and create a volume.
2. Create a new instance with a new ssh key.
3. Stop the new instance and attached the previously created volume as the boot volume.
4. Start the new instance and you should be able to login with the new ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

The log indicates that you **do not have any networking issues**. It is the ssh server on the instance that is rejecting your connection.

The first thing to **confirm is that you are connecting to the correct Amazon EC2 instance**. If an EC2 instance is stopped and started again, it *might* change public IP address (depending how it is configured). Therefore, make sure that you are connecting to the right instance.

Next, **confirm that you are using the correct username**. You are using `ubuntu@`, which is correct if the instance is using an Ubuntu AMI. However, it is possible to create additional users on a Linux computer and the PEM files are associated with specific users. Therefore, confirm that this is the correct username for use with that PEM file.

Next, **confirm that you are using the correct PEM file**. The PEM file should contain the private half of a keypair that matches the public half that is stored on the instance in the user's `~.ssh/authorized_keys` file. The log indicates that the instance is rejecting the provided keypair. Therefore, you might be using the wrong one.

Failing all this, there are some recommended steps available on: [Walkthrough: Reset Passwords and SSH Keys on Amazon EC2 Instances - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-ec2reset.html)

However, they might not work since you are using an Ubuntu instance, which might not have standard AWS software installed.

Let us know how you go!